# Allow access to wildfly port 8080 over WAN for web page

Tags: wildfly

My team needs to see a web page I have built that I am hosting *temporarily* on my local windows 10 laptop using Wildfly 11.

I have changed the configuration **standalone.xml** from commented value to this

```
   <interface name="public">
       <!--   <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>-->
             <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:xx.xx.xxx.xxx}"/> 
    </interface>
```

Where xxx is equal to my ip address as determined from my internet provider's control page.  I can ping that address from any of my local machines and my co-workers can also ping the address.

However, when I go to run with this value in the xml, I get the error:
***Failed to start service org.wildfly.network.interface.public: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.network.interface.public: WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve interface public***

What else do I need to do to enable access to the port?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you run Wildfly on the command line with something like:

`bin\standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0`

This will have Wildfly bind to all available interfaces.  For testing this should be safe - it should be ok to bind to more than on interface.  You will not need any changes in `standalone.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

If your "xx.xx.xxx.xxx" is not the IP number of an interface *on your machine*, then you won't be able to bind to it. You can only bind to an interface that is actually present on the host. Typically the IP number of your machine, as seen from the public Internet, will not be the same as an IP number on the machine itself. You need to bind your HTTP server to the machine's real IP number (not localhost, 127.0.0.1, but the IP corresponding to some real network connection -- Ethernet, Wifi, whatever) and you need to configure your Internet router to forward packets addressed to port 8080 to the IP number of your wildfly host.

I would think that, if your co-workers are on the same site as you, they would have access to your machine without going through the public Internet. In that case, all you need to do is to bind the port to the (non-localhost) IP number of your machine, and have your colleagues use that IP number. You might also need to configure any firewall you have -- either on your wildfly host or your router -- to allow access to port 8080.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  My next questions: 1. how do I get the actual wifi address of my machine  The xxx I used is the address given at my infinity router...  2.  its windows 10 - do you know how to configure the firewall to access 8080.  I see how to open the access for applications but not for ports. Lastly, we are a remote team and have no common site!  Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Sorry -- I think you'll get better responses to questions like this on a Windows forum. I would get my IP number by typing "ipconfig"  at the prompt. The rest of it I'm afraid you'll need somebody with more Windows knowledge. Bear in mind that, if you have a router that allocates IP numbers using DHCP, your IP number might change regularly.